# Could I find the function invoked by an event in run-time?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to find that when a user fires an event, such as click a button, what function(s) does this event invoke at run-time?  Would it be possible?

Comment: What javascript engine are you using? Or, are you trying to capture this in the browser?

Comment: I'd like use some javascript scripts to capture it if possible. And which javascript engine is not critical but I'm going to use Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

interesting question. add some debugging alert(), you will know what functions are triggered.

p.s. actually, the "function" you mean is the JavaScript internal function or the user-defined functions?

Comment: I am guessing it is the internal functions, which is why I wasn't able to answer it without more details.

Comment: I would prefer user-defined functions. Basically I'm thinking to do some kind of profiling, by which I mean to trace the follow of functions handling users interactions. For example, when users click a button, it triggers an event handler, and what I'd like to know is which "real" functions handles this request. If users then click a link, which functions handling, so on and so forth...

Comment: BTW, I'd like it to be transparent to users so no alert() is prompted. Basically, it's not for debugging but for execution tracing. Also, I do want to change the source code but like to have a generic solution for an implemented application.